# GLKit's GLKMatrix4 class not available in MonoTouch

Tags: opengl-es, xamarin.ios, opengl-es-2.0, glkit

As I understand it, we should be able to use `GLKit` in our MonoTouch apps (see http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/releases/MonoTouch_5/MonoTouch_5.3).

Unfortunately, I cannot find `GLKit`'s `GLKMatrix4` class in the MonoTouch library.

Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it, it's named `Matrix4` and it lives in the `OpenTK-1.0.dll` assembly.

Answer (score 2):

The following samples both use GLKit:

https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/tree/monotouch-5.4/GLCameraRipple

https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/tree/monotouch-5.4/RosyWriter

They both require MonoTouch 5.3.xx (as of August 6th 2012, that is the Beta release).